# how we I modify execute table and their fields in SQL server 2008 express database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

[image]

(after saving 1st error dialog box)

[image]

(after click on cancel)

[image]

(after click save text file as shown in 1st screen shot  )

The problem is , when i add field or modify the datatype value for executed table it shows the error that database table can't modify.

Plz solve my problem. i face to much problem to add  or to change something in field of any table.

when i do right click on any table , i can't get modify button..?

I had installed SQL Server 2008 Express edition.

Comment: please add error details, screenshots, how are you trying to make the change? using SSMS design tools?

Comment: @LuisLL added error screen shot!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to 'Tools' Menu
2. Select 'Options...'
3. From tree view at the left of window select 'Designers'
4. Clear three checkboxes: 
       'Warn about difference detection'
       and 'warn about table affected' 
       and 'Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation'

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to modify the fields of your table?
Why doing it through Wizard when you can simply use the [ALTER TABLE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) command to modify it.
But you must first make sure that there is no dependencies on other tables (foreign keys, etc.)

[This link can help also.](http://infogoal.com/sql/sql-alter-table.htm)

Comment: yes i want to modify the fields of table.but when i right click on any table the ALTER TAB shows not active? can you help me and explain more .. plz.... @Nadeem_MK

Comment: Try verifying the dependencies. Maybe you've got a foreign key in your table or a column in your table that is a foreign key on another table. If you wish to modify the corresponding column, you'll have to drop the dependency first